# R - Drawing a random ordered sample

Tags: r, random

In R, I currently have the following code:

```
    sample(1:15,sample(1:15,1))
```

This draws values of random size in a randomized order. However, for my application, the order must be kept the same.

I cannot simply order the values after each draw as this is computationally inefficient. For my application, I would like to draw from a sample of ordered values, which will greatly reduce the sample size and thus the computation time.

Some examples:

```
    > 7 9 13 14
    > 1 5 6
    > 3 4 8 10 11 14 15
    > 2
    > 2 4 6 8 9
```

EDIT: Each value in the draw must also be unique.

Comment: Are you looking for `sort` ?

Comment: A random ordered sample seems like a difficult concept to create because the number of elements of the output would be difficult to standardise. For example for 1:15 what would happen if the first draw (random process) was 15? The process should stop, so specifying an `n` is difficult. Maybe this would be of help: `seq(1, 15, sample(1:15, 1))`

Comment: `seq(sample(1:15,1), 15, sample(1:15, 1))` Thanks Lyzande

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by stepping through your list and at each step thinking about how big is the probability that this value will be selected when sampling. This is exactly what this function does

```
### Function that will select N values and preserve the order
mySample <- function(values,N){

        size <- length(values)

        values[sapply(1:size, function(i){
                    select <- as.logical(rbinom(1,1,N/(size+1-i)))
                    if(select) N <<- N - 1
                    select
        })]

}
```

Comment: `mySample(1:15,sample(1:15,1))` Thanks nist